# Overwritten data in Matlab loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface, loops

I've got the following code for a Push-button in a GUI, where it asks for a pair of coordinates (X,Y), saved in a vector Z.

I want it to save different .mat files with different names (I've achieved that already) for a specific number of iterations (3 in this case), clearing the edit boxes each time a value of Z is saved. The problem is that it overwrites the past values, keeping only the last one in the first file, and generating NaN's on the other ones.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   folder=pwd;                                                             %Current folder

   x=str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String'));
   y=str2double(get(handles.edit2,'String'));
   z=[x y];

   k=1;
   ng=3;
  while k<=ng
    baseFileName=sprintf('data%02d.mat',k);
    fullFileName=fullfile(folder,baseFileName);
    save(fullFileName);
    S.(sprintf('z%d',k))=z;
    save(baseFileName,'-struct','S');
    k=k+1;

     if k<=ng;
       set(handles.edit1,'String','')
       set(handles.edit2,'String','')   
       x=str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String'));
       y=str2double(get(handles.edit2,'String'));
       z=[x y];        
     end
  end
```

Comment: In a single call back, value of z is not changing. Secondly, I tried your code for saving files and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Please try to execute this code only:  while k<=ng
    baseFileName=sprintf('data%02d.mat',k);
    fullFileName=fullfile(folder,baseFileName);
    save(fullFileName);
    S.(sprintf('z%d',k))=z;
    save(baseFileName,'-struct','S');
    k=k+1;
end

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I only use the code you suggest my 3 files have te same value (the last one entered), instead of saving every pair of coordinates introduced

Comment: Because variable z is not changing in this function call.

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't the "S.(sprintf('z%d',k))=z; save(baseFileName,'-struct','S');" section enough? Do I need to change something besides the variable name inside the loop to save all the values?

Comment: I agree you are changing the file name in every iteration but I cannot see that value of z is changing.  It seems to me that value of z remains same in all iterations. You call z=[x y] and then enters in loop and save same z in different files. May be I am missing something here, please correct me I am wrong.

Comment: mmmm I guess you're right, but that's exactly what I can't do, the values of z are overwritten or are NaN's. Any suggestion?